# What is the rank of the module $\mathbb F_p[[x,y]]$ over its subring $\mathbb F_p[[x^{p^m},y^{p^n}]]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Consider the ring $M:=\mathbb F_p[[x,y]]$ and subring $N:=\mathbb F_p[[x^{p^m},y^{p^n}]]$, where $\mathbb F_p$ is the field of $p$-elements and $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then $M$ is a finitely generated module over $N$ with the generating set $G:=\{x^iy^j:~0 \leq i \leq p^m-1,~0 \leq j \leq p^n-1\}.$

Want to show $G$ is indeed a basis for $M$. Or in other words, the rank of $M$ is $p^{m+n}$.

---

Method1:

Since $G$ is a generator of $M$ over $N$, any element $m(x,y) \in M$ can be written as $m(x,y)=g_1n_1(x^{p^m},y^{p^n})+g_2n_2(x^{p^m},y^{p^n})+\cdots+(\text{upto finite combination})$, where $g_1, g_2, \cdots \in G$.
But still, we have to show the minimality $G$. If we remove just one element $x^i y^j$ from $G$, then we have to show there is at least one element $m(x,y \in M$ which cannot be written as a finite linear combination of $G \setminus \{x^iy^j\}$ and $N$.

If I consider the particular case for $m=1, n=2$: then we have

$G=\{1, x, y, xy, xy^2, xy^3\}$, $N=\mathbb F_2[[x^2, y^4]]=\left\langle \mathbb F_2, x^2, y^4 \right\rangle$ and $M=\mathbb F_2[[x,y]]$.

Let us remove $y$ from the generating set $G$ and consider the element $m(x,y)=x^5+y^6 \in \mathbb F_2[[x,y]]$. We claim that $m(x,y)$ cannot be written as a finite linear combination of elements of the sets $G':=G \setminus \{x\}=\{1, y, xy, xy^2, xy^3\}$ and $N$.

If possible, let $x^5+y^{6}= g_1n_1+g_2n_2,~g_i \in G',~n_i \in N$, then we must have $g_1n_1=x^5$ and $g_2n_2=y^{6}$.

Clearly, $g_1n_1=x^5$ cannot have a solution in $G'$, this only can happen if $g_1=x, n_1=(x^2)^2.$.  But $x \notin G'$. Thus, $G'$ cannot generate $M$. In other words, $G$ is the minimal generating set. So a basis for $M$, in this case.

How to follow the general case ?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, sorry. You are right. I meant $p=2$ initially. Anyway, I have edited  the question. I think it is relevant now. In your second comment, you are asking for linear combination to equate with zero to check whether they are independent or not? Is it?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, If i consider the particular case $p=2,m=1,n=2$, $G=\{1, x, y, xy, xy^2, xy^3\}$, then consider the linear combination $c_1 \cdot 1+c_2 \cdot x+c_3 \cdot y+c_4 \cdot xy+c_5 \cdot xy^2+c_6 \cdot xy^3=0$, where $c_i \in \left\langle \mathbb F_p, x^2, y^4 \right\rangle$. This is zero iff $c_i=p$ for all $i$. So the $G$ is linearly independent set.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez,well thank you for the clarification. Yes I got it now.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, thanks. I indeed posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments
by Mariano Suárez-Álvarez, I am writing the answer:

---

For more generality, given a field $k$, consider the corresponding ring $M:=k[[x,y]]$ of power series and its subring $N:=k[[x^m,y^n]],~m,n \in \mathbb N$. Then, $M$ is a $N$-module where the action of $N$ on $M$ is just multiplication of power series. Besides that, $M$ is finitely generated by the set $\Theta:=\{x^iy^j:~0 \leq i \leq m, 0\leq j \leq n\}$. We want to show the set $\Theta$ is indeed a basis for $M$. For example, consider the linear combination
\begin{align} &\sum_{l=1}^{mn} c_i \cdot \left( \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x^iy^j\right)=0,~(\text{where}~c_i:=c_i(a,x^m,y^n) \in N,~a \in \mathbb F_p) \\& \Rightarrow c_1 \cdot 1+c_2 \cdot x+c_3 \cdot y+c_4 \cdot xy+\cdots+c_{mn}x^{m-1}y^{m-1}=0.\end{align} The LHS $c_1 \cdot 1+c_2 \cdot x+c_3 \cdot y+c_4 \cdot xy+\cdots+c_{mn}x^{m-1}y^{m-1}$ vanishes if and only if $c_i=p=0 \in \mathbb F_p$. Therefore, the generating set $\Theta$ is linearly independent and hence a basis for $M$ over $N$. Note that $\# \Theta=mn$ and thus the free-rank of $M$ is $mn$.

Finally, the answer to the given question follows trivially by replacing $(m,n) \to (p^m,p^n)$.